# Where should I put the "down" file to prevent Chef from starting

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I am running Open Source Chef 11 Server and a dozen or so Linux and SmartOs servers running chef-client. At one point I created a file on one of my linux servers with the filename of "down" in a specific directory and that prevented the chef-client from running, even after reboot. I have since deleted this file and I cannot remember which directory I had put that file in. I can no longer find any documentation that this existed or works. Did I imagine this?

I realize the point of Chef is to have chef-client running at all times but sometimes it is useful to disable the chef-client while experimenting with the server configuration.

I believe this "down" file might be related to runit.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it.

If I create the file in /etc/sv/chef-client

```
# touch /etc/sv/chef-client/down
```

then run

```
# sv status chef-client
```

I get back

```
down: chef-client: 85480s; run: log: (pid 8000) 93131s
```

If I remove the down file I get back

```
down: chef-client: 85539s, normally up; run: log: (pid 8000) 93190s
```